# Insert a comment before a key in Ruamel.yaml

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I am using the Ruamel Python library to programmatically edit human-edited YAML files.

I am struggling to understand how I can insert comments into structured data.

I have some data:

```
a:
  b: banana
  c: apple
  d: orange
```

I would like to add a comment and a new key:

```
a:
  b: banana
  c: apple
  d: orange
  # This is my comment
  e: pear
```

Is it possible to do this using `ruamel.yaml`, and if so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes that is possible, as you can check by doing a round-trip:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

with open('your_input.yaml') as fp:
    data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

the printed output will match your input, so somehow the comment is inserted into the `data` hierarchy of structures, preserved, and written out when dumping.

In `ruamel.yaml` the comments are attached to wrapper classes for `lists` or `dict`s, which you check with `print(type(data['a'])`: it is a `CommentedMap` (from `ruamel.yaml.comment.py`). The comment information for the value of `a` hangs of an attribute `_yaml_comment` that you can access via the property `ca`:

```
cm = data['a']
print(cm.ca)
```

gives:

```
items={'e': [None, [CommentToken(value='# This is my comment\n')], None, None]})
```

This shows the comment is associated with the key `e`, that is following the comment. Unfortunately the `CommentToken` cannot just be created by calling it like it is represented (i.e. `CommentToken(value='# This is my comment\n')`), it needs a little more work as it needs at least a start `Mark`.

There is no "helper" routine to create such a comment, but by looking at `CommentedMap` and its base class `CommentedBase` you can come up with the following ¹:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

if not hasattr(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap, "yaml_set_comment_before_key"):
    def my_yaml_set_comment_before_key(self, key, comment, column=None,
                                       clear=False):
        """
        append comment to list of comment lines before key, '# ' is inserted
            before the comment
        column: determines indentation, if not specified take indentation from
                previous comment, otherwise defaults to 0
        clear: if True removes any existing comments instead of appending
        """
        key_comment = self.ca.items.setdefault(key, [None, [], None, None])
        if clear:
            key_comment[1] = []
        comment_list = key_comment[1]
        if comment:
            comment_start = '# '
            if comment[-1] == '\n':
                comment = comment[:-1]  # strip final newline if there
        else:
            comment_start = '#'
        if column is None:
            if comment_list:
                 # if there already are other comments get the column from them
                column = comment_list[-1].start_mark.column
            else:
                column = 0
        start_mark = ruamel.yaml.error.Mark(None, None, None, column, None, None)
        comment_list.append(ruamel.yaml.tokens.CommentToken(
            comment_start + comment + '\n', start_mark, None))
        return self

    ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap.yaml_set_comment_before_key = \
        my_yaml_set_comment_before_key
```

with `CommentedMap` extended with this method you can then do:

```
yaml_str = """\
a:
  b: banana
  c: apple
  d: orange
  e: pear
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
cm = data['a']

cm.yaml_set_comment_before_key('e', "This is Alex' comment", column=2)
cm.yaml_set_comment_before_key('e', 'and this mine')
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

to get:

```
a:
  b: banana
  c: apple
  d: orange
  # This is Alex' comment
  # and this mine one
  e: pear
```

Unless you read in a comment, there is no way to query `cm` which column 
the comment should be in, to align it with the key `e` (that column is determined on writing out the data structure). You might be tempted to store a special value (`-1`?) and try to determine this during output, but you have little context while streaming out. You can of course determine/set the column to the nesting level (`1`) and multiply that by the indent (the one you give to `round_trip_dump`, which defaults to `2`)

*The comments facilities were meant for preservation in round-tripping, and not initially for modification or inserting new ones, so the interface is not guaranteed to be stable. With that in mind make sure you create a single routine or a set of routines around `yaml_set_comment_before_key()`, to make your changes, so you only have a single module to update if the interface changes (the capability of being able to attach a comment will not go away, the method of doing so might however change)*

---

¹ <sub>Maybe not you, but since I am the author of [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml), I should be able to find my way in the underdocumented code.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much again @Anthon.  However, you have left a debugging line in on the line beginning key_comment, where "'e'" should be 'key'.  Also, the method forces you to add a whitespace at the end of the line if you want a blank comment line.  So I preferred to change it so that the user needs to specify the white space immediately after #.

Comment: Not so much debugging, as well as first getting the functionality and then transforming it into a method, thereby forgetting the on value->parameter conversion. Thanks for catching that. I also updated to test for comment not to be the empty string (which would lead to an exception) but you don't get a space now before the newline (i.e. it directly follows the `#`). Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Future Visitors,  for version ```ruamel.yaml==0.15.94``` use ```ruamel.yaml.yaml_set_comment_before_after_key('e', before="This is Alex' comment", after="This is another comment after the key")```

Comment: @Anthon What would you think of editing a brief note into your answer to reflect what DDrake just posted in a comment?

Comment: @DavidZ I have been postponing updating my ruamel.yaml answers for comment handling as the code for that has to be changed (in a future version). That will mean non-compatible changes (which people should recon with as ruamel.yaml is pre 1.0 and the above routines are not public API). And I don't want to update answers multiple times, if I had the time for that I would spent it on (unpaid) work on ruamel.yaml in the first place. So your suggestion is not bad, but I won't do that now

Comment: @Anthon Understood, it certainly makes sense to devote your time to the most important priorities.